# How to parse object as HTML using mechanize?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I am very much new to mechanize and in fact python too. I am trying to write script that auto fill ups  form with my custom data and after a long search over web I landed to mechanize page and found something I was looking for.

I am able to retrieve the web page in which I need to auto fill the fields. But the web page that I retrieved is not in clean html format. It contains stuffs like \n  like

```
\n<input type="text" name="jcaptcha" value="" id="appEntry_jcaptcha" style="width: 240px;"/></div> </div>\n        </div>\n\n    <div>\n   <input type="hidden" name="statusType" value="NEWLICENSE" id="appEntry_statusType"/>\n        <div align="center"    id="wwctrl_confirmBox">
```

I got this from the code

```
import mechanize

br= mechanize.Browser()

dotm = 'http://example.com'

br.set_handle_robots(False)

br.open(dotm)

br.select_form(nr=0)

br['someField'] = ['value']
br['someField'] = ['someValue']

response = br.submit()

print(response.read())
```

I got this web page after doing br.submit() from some previous page. The actual form that I wanted to auto fill is actually on 'response'. So, how can I render the messy stuff containing \n to a clean HTML so that I can select input fields over there and auto fill  with my custom data? It would be great if you showed some example of selecting fields over there and auto filling them.